# Need to get Result from filtering item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simple code for filtering multiple item, so far its working

Here is the code  :

```
<div class="container btn-group tags" data-toggle="buttons">

    <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="myBtn">
        <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" /> Arts
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn">
        <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" /> Computers
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn">
        <input type="checkbox" rel="health" /> Health
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="myBtn">
        <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" /> Video Games
    </label>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="results">
        <div class="container arts computers">
            Result 1
        </div>
        <div class="container video-games">
            Result 2
        </div>
        <div class="container computers health video-games">
            Result 3
        </div>
        <div class="container arts video-games">
            Result 4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the script :

```
 $('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function()
{
    var $lis = $('.results > div'),
            $checked = $('input:checked');

    if ($checked.length)
    {
        var selector = $checked.map(function ()
        {
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join('');

        $lis.hide().filter(selector).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $lis.show();
    }
});
```

My question is, if i have filter let said A - Z letter, and some one select A & M how to displaying the letter that he selected? and give an option to clear all the field by clicking clear button?

here is the fidle http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/g9SAQ/

Thanks,

Comment: sorry, not clear - can you give an example case

Comment: Hi, this is the fidle : http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/g9SAQ/ and this is screenshot i take from website http://www.screencast.com/t/njhZTcmAAn

Comment: my answer has been updated to address your question/concern.. please check if its correct now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your fiddle to ALERT when a box is checked (so you can see how to display value of checkbox checked) and added a button to clear all (so you can see how to reset result list and clear all checkbox checks)

[Working Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9SAQ/3/)

```
<button onclick="$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');$('.results > div').show();$('.checkedItem').html('');">Clear All</button>
```

i've added a new div to put the last checked box value into:

```
<div class="checkedItem">checked item will go here once clicked</div>
```

and here is how its put in:

```
 $('.checkedItem').html($(this).attr('rel'));
```

Comment: Hi eric, yes the clear button is functioning well. But the checked is alert, can you tell how to displaying the checked item on the page? line <div>checked item here</div>. Thanks

Comment: Yes, perfectly working. Thank you very much erik. Unfortunately still cant vote so far. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `id="myBtn"` as `id` must be `unique` and add `class category` to the `checkboxes`
Also add a `checkbox` whose `id` is `clear` to `clear` the `div` like,

```
$('div.tags').delegate('#clear', 'change', function() {
    $('.category').prop('checked',false);
    $('.results > div').hide();
});
```

And modfy your `category checkboxes` like,

```
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox].category', 'change', function() {
    if($('.category:checked').length){// if clear is checked then uncheck it
       $('#clear').prop('checked',false);
    }
    var $lis = $('.results > div'),
        $checked = $('input.category:checked');
    if ($checked.length){
        var selector = $checked.map(function (){
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join(', '); // join the array with ', '
        $lis.hide().filter(selector).show();
    } else{
        $lis.show();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/584kv/)

**Updated,** if you want to show `active div's` try this,

**CSS**

```
.active{
   background:#BBE4E7;
}
```

In **Jquery** replace the lines

1. `$lis.hide().filter(selector).show();` **by** `$lis.removeClass('active').filter(selector).addClass('active');`
2. `$('.results > div').hide();` **by** `$('.results > div').removeClass('active');`

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/584kv/1/)

Comment: Hi rohan, i can see your demo. Clearing selection is working. Can you check how to displaying checked item in some place like in picture link above?